# OpenSSH: Different Authentication Methods

Tags: linux, ssh

I have the need of having users logging in to a CentOS system with different authentication methods. Some using password and others using public key.

I followed the methods mentioned here:
[How can I setup OpenSSH per-user authentication methods?](https://serverfault.com/questions/150153/how-can-i-setup-openssh-per-user-authentication-methods)

However, I am not successful in having successful password based login.

In the sshd_config file, I have:

```
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive,publickey
PasswordAuthentication no

Match User newton
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match all
```

Update:
   I see that the issue is only when I have 2FA enabled with google authentication and I have the line:

```
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive,publickey
```

Though for the user newton, I have set password authentication I see the following error:

```
[root@localhost]# ssh newton@50.39.213.152
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Habe you tried this ? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/creating-user-specific-authentication-methods-in-ssh

Comment: @Tolsadus, Yes. I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: If you have a publickey denied, means that http://askubuntu.com/questions/337757/how-to-fix-permission-denied-public-key-error I really recommend you to go through the doc I posted below ! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although @Tolsadus answer probably points to the correct solution, it does not answer the question clearly.

In short, manual page for `ssh_config` is a good start to understand how the config parser in ssh works (the same rules apply for `sshd_config`):

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used

This means that your example will set `PasswordAuthentication` to `no` for all users and for `newton` user will not overwrite it (because it is already set). To work it around, you should set the default values in the `Match` block. This will have the expected effect on `newton` user:

```
Match User newton
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match all
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't totally sure about the rules that the first obtained value will be used !

Answer (score 2):

[Perfect explanation](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Limit_access_to_openssh_features_with_the_Match_keyword.html) how to use the match option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

In your case, you should do like that "real" world example
https://gist.github.com/kjellski/5940875

You can find that match with addresses, but also users that is commented.

**EDIT / UPDATE**

@Jakuje properly answered the question, way more precise than mine.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you made a mistake on your public key in /path/to/.ssh/authorized_keys for newton ?
(that's why it would be refused and denied)
You can check your logs to have more info